# Send email using column values as conditions

Tags: excel, vba, email, conditional-statements

I need to mail the content of each line of a worksheet to an email address in column "U". The program needs to verify "needs to be sent" (Column V) and if it has already been "emailed" (Column W).

There is a similar question but it did not help me.

Some details:

- The email address column (Column U) is a formula that searches the email with a VLOOKUP formula from another sheet.
- The macro runs (no debugs), but nothing happens. The draft on the mail is not created.
- I tried using just one condition and it creates all the drafts for the entire list (seems to work normally)

```vb
Sub email()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    For Each cell In Worksheets("query_export_results").Columns("U").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
            LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "V").Value) = "Y" And _
            LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "W").Value) = "" Then
            With OutMail
                .To = Cells(cell.Row, "U").Value
                .Subject = "Notificação de Não Conformidade | Non-Compliance Notification"
                .Body = "Notificação de Registro de Não Conformidade."
                .display
                '.Send
            End With
            Cells(cell.Row, "W").Value = "sent"
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell
    
    'Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you mean by "I tried using just one condition and it creates all the drafts for the entire list (seems to work normally)"?  What is the "one condition"?

Comment: Hello, sir! Thanks for answering.
What I mean is that on the line "If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _"
If I remove the "And _" and do not use the other two subsequent lines, it works. but create drafts for all the lines of the sheet.

Comment: I think problem is in here `LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "W").Value) = ""` When cell is empty then excel can not convert it to lower case. Try `Cells(cell.Row, "W")=""`

Answer (score 0):

Your condition `LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "V").Value) = "Y"` will never be true, because you have an **uppercase** "Y" but you are testing against a **lowercase** cell value.  Either change the `LCase` to `UCase` or change "Y" to "y".